# How to display image from a folder using button with Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to display an image in my streamlit web app using a button.

So whenever user clicks the button the image must be displayed onto the streamlit web app.

The code given below:

```
feature_choice2 = st.sidebar.multiselect("Plot Size", task2)
if st.button('Find Blueprint'):
    if feature_choice2 == '3-marla':
        imagee = cv2.imread('Floor_plans/3-marla.png')
        cv2.imshow('Image', imagee)
        st.image(imagee, caption='3 marla plot')
```

Answer (score 5):

Streamlit doesn't upload image in it's natural form so thus has to be converted into an array and then use it. Hope this helps:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a image file", type="jpg")

if uploaded_file is not None:
    # Convert the file to an opencv image.
    file_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(uploaded_file.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    opencv_image = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, 1)

    # Now do something with the image! For example, let's display it:
    st.image(opencv_image, channels="BGR")
```

Answer (score 2):

`cv2.imshow` won't work while displaying images in streamlit since it would open another separate window.

Unless you plan to perform any operation on the image itself,

```
from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st

feature_choice2 = st.sidebar.multiselect("Plot Size", task2)
if st.button('Find Blueprint'):
    if feature_choice2 == '3-marla':
        image = Image.open('./Floor_plans/3-marla.png')
        st.image(image, caption='3 marla plot',use_column_width=True)
```

Note:
For this to work your directory structure should be

```
|- app.py # Your Streamlit Script
|- Floor_plans
   |- 3-marla.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work more effectively as did it on my one of the instafilter open-cv application.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
import streamlit as st 

# Function to Read and Manupilate Images
def load_image(img):
    im = Image.open(img)
    image = np.array(im)
    return image

# Uploading the File to the Page
uploadFile = st.file_uploader(label="Upload image", type=['jpg', 'png'])

# Checking the Format of the page
if uploadFile is not None:
    # Perform your Manupilations (In my Case applying Filters)
    img = load_image(uploadFile)
    st.image(img)
    st.write("Image Uploaded Successfully")
else:
    st.write("Make sure you image is in JPG/PNG Format.")
```